# as adjective as structure

Tags: comparative-constructions, as

I found a sentence on an online English test.

> Question: **More money is now spent on fuel than before.**
>
> Answer: **Not as much money was spent on fuel before as now.**

I have learnt "comparative structure like "as adjective as ", "adjective than." I found as adj as, as much/many noun as. But I did not know which structures are those sentences?  I really want to know this structre "not as adj noun v as noun "

Answer (score 1):

This is a special use.

To link to http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/sameas.html.

Look at the section:"Comparative Expressions As / So / Such"->"AS + NOUN".

For example,"It's not as easy a decision as that."

Comment: I understand that the post asks for a link, but usually we discourage answers that are basically "link only". Please provide an explanation in this answer.

Comment: @Max: Well, the question *used to* ask for links… but I soon [settled its hash](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/settle+hash).

Answer (score 1):

When you are a making a quantitative comparison. You can use the structure `As much + uncountable noun/noun phrase + as`. Your example

> Not as much money was spent on fuel before as now.

is correct!

For a countable noun. You should use *many*. `As many + countable noun/noun phrase + as`. For example,

> I try to give you as many books as I can.